# How to find the cosets of the circle group T in the nonzero complex numbers C*

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

C* is a group containing the complex numbers in the form $z=a+bi$. T is a subgroup of C* containing the complex numbers whose absolute value is equal to 1 (i.e. $|z| = 1$).

I am having trouble finding the left and right cosets, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;z,w\in\Bbb C^*\;$ . Observe that

$$zT=wT\iff z^{-1}w\in T\iff\left|z^{-1}w\right|=1\iff|z|=|w|$$

Can you now see, both geometrically and algebraically, what the cosets in the quotient group $\;\Bbb C^*/T\;$ are?